# How to use extension in another view controller class and how to make it?

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

How to make a extension in swift and how to call that extension into another view controller class ?

This is my AlertController.swift class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIAlertController {

    static func alertCtrl(title: String, message: String, buttonTitle: String) -> UIAlertController {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(action)

        return alertController
    }
}
```

This is my Main View Controller Class where we call that extension.

```
import UIKit

class SubmitDetailsVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //how to call the extension here.
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on your requirement. first specify it. [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: let alertController = UIAlertController.alertCtrl(title: "title", message: "message", buttonTitle: "buttonTitle")

Comment: If your question involves how to call a `UIAlertController` (and it's extension) in `viewDidLoad` - **don't**. You'll never get it to work. Call it *later* in the view controller's life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your extension in any ViewController you want

```
let alertExt = UIAlertController.alertCtrl(title: "Your title", message: "Hello world!", buttonTitle: "Title of button")
self.present(alertExt, animated: true, completion: nil)
```